# iOS Metal: casting half4 variable to float4 type

Tags: ios, shader, metal

I am using a sampler to sample from texture:

```
constexpr sampler cubeSampler(filter::linear, mip_filter::none);
half4 res = cubeTexture.sample(cubeSampler, texVec);
```

The result is of type half4 but i need to cast it to float4 in order to perform math operations. How can i perform this cast?

Comment: The result is of type `half4` because you presumably declared `cubeTexture` as a `texturecube<half>`. If you want `float4`, you should consider declaring it as a `texturecube<float>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
constexpr sampler cubeSampler(filter::linear, mip_filter::none);
half4 res = cubeTexture.sample(cubeSampler, texVec);

// cast to float4:
float4 res_float4 =  static_cast<float4>(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

`static_cast` works, or you can use the more terse converting constructor:

```
float4 res_float4 = float4(res);
```